# Is there anyway to use js on the server-side just like I would with PHP (embedded in doc)?

Tags: javascript, php, server-side

One feature I both love and hate about PHP is the ability to embed the code into the HTML. The benefit is being able to see the flow of my code. The con is the jumbled, spaghetti code that can become difficult to read at times.

For example, I am looking for something where I can have js code as preprocessed, server-side code that is executed on the backend prior to being sent to the client. This code can be embedded into my HTML document just like PHP would. Maybe the server-side JS would be wrapped in special delimeters to signify it is preprocessed.

```
<?js //start of preprocessed, server-side JS code

const hostname = "myhn";
const username = "root";
const passcode = "mypassword";
const dbname = "mydatabase";

var conn = new mysqli(hostname, username, passcode, dbname);
if (conn.connect_error) {

die();

} else {

let userId = 1;

const qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
const getUser = conn.prepare(qry);
getUser.bindParam('i',userId);
getUser.execute();
const result = getUser.fetchResult();

while(var row = result.fetchObject()){

    var firstName = row.firstName;
    var points = row.points;

}

?> //end of server-side JS code 

<p>Welcome, <a id="settings"><?js document.write(firstName); ?></a>. You have 
<?js document.write(points); ?> points. </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('#settings').addEventListener('click',()=>{

        window.confirm("Do you wish to alter your settings>");

    });

</script>

<?js 
}
?>
```

Does this exist as a feature of NodeJS, for example?

Comment: You are looking for a template engine? e.g jades, handlebar, ejs...

Comment: The code between the <script> tags would be front-end, client-side javascript, while the code in the <?js ?> delimeters would be preprocessed code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **node.js** and the **ejs** project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

On the server side you can create pages (also called *views*) that contain code like this:

```
<% if (user) { %>
  <h2><%= user.name %></h2>
<% } %>
```

You should read its documentation and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For this You Have To Use Node js with ejs or jade engine:-

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "pwd",
  database: "db"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```